# Django app with tensorflow running very slowly

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, subprocess, twilio

I have a web app created with `django` that is using `tensorflow` to generate compliments and text them to people who sign up for the service. Every time a user submits a number, I'm using `subprocess.call()` to run a separate script which creates my model and writes the AI-generated compliment to a text file, then the SMS gateway (`twilio`) uses this `.txt` file for the body of the message.

However, after submitting a valid number when it is running the model the app is loading for a very long time, like sometimes it takes 30 seconds or longer before the page stops loading and this is not ideal.

Why is this taking so long? Is it because creating the model in `tensorflow` is just a timely process? And can I do something to speed this up, should I just have it run the code to create the model earlier in the program, or should I just generate a whole bunch of compliments ahead of time and have the SMS gateway draw from that instead?

This is the script which creates the model:

```
from textgenrnn import textgenrnn
textgen = textgenrnn(weights_path='compliments_weights.hdf5',
                       vocab_path='compliments_vocab.json',
                       config_path='compliments_config.json')

textgen.generate_samples(max_gen_length=1000)
textgen.generate_to_file('textgenrnn_texts.txt', max_gen_length=1000)
```

Comment: Did you benchmark the tensorflow program without the Django project? Please add if the tensorflow program also also needs 30 seconds as well or if it runs faster.

Comment: Do you train your model every time the user submits a number? What is your model?

Comment: @allo it takes the same amount of time without the django project as well

Comment: @praveen the model is already trained, I just run a smaller script which uses the weights.hdf5, vocab.json, and config.json files to create a textgenrnn object and then it generates my sentence from that and puts it in a text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Tensorflow model is just that slow on this machine. You tested it without Django and it also needs 30 seconds, so we can skip the Django part here.

The best option to make it faster is to use `tensorflow-gpu` and a server with a Nvidia graphics card (e.g. AWS GPU instances). This usually reduces the needed time by a factor of at least 10, so you will get a waiting time that is probably acceptable for your application.

In addition you should try to decouple Django and the Tensorflow-Script to avoid loading and initializing the model for each request. Create some kind of queue system. Then your Django app write the input value into the queue and waits for the result and your Tensorflow program runs in the background and reads the values from the queue, evaluates the model and sends the result back to Django.

Comment: Okay thanks! Do you think this could be something I could use django-background-tasks for? https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @datasplice This package seems to start tasks from time to time and then stop running. You need to run the task as soon as possible, but inside a running process. So you should create a script that waits for input, e.g., on a unix socket, on a tcp port or from a redis pubsub queue, then evaluates the network and sends the output back to the django process. The script with the neural network itself should not stop after processing one input, but wait on the next input from the queue.

Comment: How to run the background job in the best way may be a topic for another question. I would not phrase it as "can I use software X" (software recommendations are off-topic here), but ask "What is the best way to combine Tensorflow and Django" or something similar.

Comment: Okay, appreciate the help and advice! I had posted another question about it but I think I have a good idea now